# How to `az ad group create` for Microsoft365 group?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, command-line-interface, microsoft365

There are two types of groups in Azure Active Directory:

- Security
- Microsoft365

[image]

I can create a new `Security` group using Azure CLI and `az ad group create --display-name TEST`.

- How do I create a new `Microsoft365` group using Azure CLI?
- Is it possible?
- If not, which CLI can I use to script this?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer. Apparently there is an `Office365 CLI` [found here](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/aad/o365group/o365group-add/).

The command to create a new Azure Active Directory Microsoft 365 Group is:

- `m365 aad o365group add [options]`